# Adobe fonts not loading in Safari (with Next.js)

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, adobe

I'm using  Next.js, and trying to import some Adobe Fonts inside of the `_document.js` file as explained [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/font-optimization).

The fonts render properly in Chrome and Firefox, but they don't load at all in Safari (I've checked the network tab and they don't seem to be downloaded). Here's what the code looks like in my `document.js` file.

```js
 <Head>
   <link
     rel="stylesheet"
     href="https://use.typekit.net/mysecretkey.css"
   ></link>
</Head>
```

Has anyone experienced this before? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I was a victim of this once, where I had a badly named font. Missed `"` and incorrect style

Comment: Yep you're 100% right. I just checked and this was exactly the problem. Looks like safari really cares about letter-casing. I had "DIN-2014" which worked fine on chrome and firefox, but safari wanted "din-2014". Thanks!